# Multi language wordpress site not able to show images

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

I have a **Multi language WordPress** website in 2 languages -

1. Japanese url - [here](http://www.yomeiri.com/)
2. English url - [here](http://www.yomeiri.com/en/)

The problem is that the **website is not showing the images** that are there kept inside the *"wp-content>uploads"* folder.

You can check that the images are there but not showing. Eg.

1. Open url - [here](http://www.yomeiri.com/)
2. Under the section "私たちのギャラリー" the images are not showing but the images are there. Eg "Manushi" has the image **http://yomeiri.com/en/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/12/maxresdefault.jpg** which is put on img's src property but is not showing. Same thing with other images too.

[image]

[image]

What is the problem please help?

Comment: Potentially an agressive referrer checking script or plugin. Unfortunetly your question is fairly broad. Why does `/en/` get added to your image content? is that divided up by language too?

Comment: Its wordpress mulilanguage site. That's why /en/ is coming on the images url. If it is some script or plugin how can i correct this?

Comment: Does the wordpress multilingual options have anything about "Translate existing media in all languages"?